# Why does paint on the table blister and wood swells?

Tags: wood, paint

My friend's study table looks like this. Why does this happen? Why does the wood under the paint swell and the paint peel?[image]

Comment: is it solid wood? .... probably got wet

Answer (score 2):

Although it is difficult to tell by the picture, the damage shown is typical of what happens when painted [particle board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_board) (which swells when exposed to moisture) is allowed to get wet.

Why does it expand? Because it is made by compressing sawdust with a binding resin, and unless it is protected from moisture the binder is compromised and it "decompresses".